# Weka Decision Tree getting too big (out of memory)

Tags: machine-learning, out-of-memory, weka, j48

For classification I used Weka's J48 decision tree to build a model on several nominal attributes. Now there is more data for classification (5 nonimal attributes) but each attribute has 3000 different values. I used J48 with pruning but it ran out of memory (associated 4GB). With a smaller dataset, I saw in the output, that J48 keeps all leaves with no instances associated with it. Why are they kept in the model? Should I switch to another classifcation algorithm?

Comment: You need to do some feature processing, it is very not wise to throw in a categorical feature with 3000 values to a decision tree model.

Comment: You could set J48's minNumObj hyperparameter to a higher value, say 20, or try the rules/PART algorithm which is (according to the context menu documentation) a simplified version of C4.5 / J48 - maybe it needs less memory

Comment: "keeps all leaves with no instances" -- is this in the test set? There may be no instances with those values in the test set.